# PCRE Regex Function Parser

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a specific requirement to parse some basic pseudo code in (wait for it) PHP. The type of string that might need parsing is as follows:

```
MID(DATEDIFF(ymd,131001,131201),0,1)
```

Such that:

```
DATEDIFF(ymd,131001,131201) = 61
MID(60,0,1) = 6
```

The parsing of the individual expressions is not the problem, the problem is extracting the nested function calls with regex. I would really appreciate some input that might put me on the right track to be able to extract the function calls and their nested index - i.e.: Find the calls for MID (index = 0) and DATEDIFF (index = 1), which would allow me to evaluate the highest indexes first adn use those results in the lower indexes.

The best i can do with my feeble PCRE skills is the following:

```
$expression = 'MID(DATEDIFF(dmy,011213,021213),0,1)';
$regexp = '/^(DATEDIFF\(|MID\()(.*)\)/';
if (preg_match_all($regexp, $expression, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    var_dump($matches); 
else echo "no match" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Ideally i would like to be able to extract the nested depth and position of each pseudo function present. If i could see that DATEDIFF(dmy,011213) was nested within brackets (depth=1) and that there is also a function present at depth 0 then i would be able to evaluate the depth=1 functions before looking at the depth=0 functions which need the "deeper" result set to get started. Does that help? please let me know if its not clear - i'm struggling to express it!

Comment: @puppyFlo [Some regex-fu](http://regex101.com/r/yR5jO8), quite difficult to explain ...

Comment: @HamZa - wow, thank you. I'm going to need to take a bit of time to digest the detail on the link and i'll get back to you once i begin to get my head round it! Regex are definitely a dark art to the uninformed!

Comment: @HamZa - as you were first and i've been working with your regex would you like to add as an answer and i'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to this regex:

```
(?P<function>\w+)(?=
    (?P<body>
       \(
          (?:
            [^()]
            |
            (?&body)
          )*
       \)
    )
)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/sY3eG0

Comment: Thanks Alex - that uncannily similar to the comment from @HamZa

Comment: I'm still working it into a PHP script and will post here once done - thanks again